# (Spring) How to force jpa to update with If-Match "*"?

Tags: spring, jpa, etag

I have an (put) endpoint in some micro service lets call it A which can call from outside of the domain and from another micro service inside the same domain.

I implemented if-match header with @Version annotation and working just fine but i need additional feature such as; they want to call this endpoint from another micro service at the same domain with "*" and i have to tell JPA to accept request without optimistic-locking.

How could i force JPA to update if the request come from same domain with "*"?

Answer (score 0):

Ok i just fixed this. We were using JPA totaly wrong when updating entity. When update some entity you should just get this entity from repo and set its fields. For example;

FooData comes service layer from controller and FooEntity comes from repo. You should use FooData to just check fields of FooEntity and set null to (@Version) tagged row_version. This means jpa can automaticaly increase number and worked well to me.

**Wrong Behaviour**: Convert FooData into BarEntity type-> Set new values to BarEntity and repository save the new entity.

If i'm still doing wrong please update me, I'll be appreciated.